# Change time format in log file

Tags: log, sed, squid, date

I have squid log file in follow format:

```
31/Jul/2014:13:44:52 +0400.701      0 172.16.204.59 TCP_DENIED/407 5232 GET http://vec01.maps.yandex.net/tiles? - NONE/- text/html
```

but log analyzer need time in unix format.

date command can convert to unix format:

```
date -d "31 Jul 2014 12:51:57 +0400" '+%s'
1406796717
```

but I can't compose `sed` command for change format.
Please help me.

Comment: Do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663648/change-time-format-in-log-file/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following perl command to replace all dates in your existing logs:

```
cat my_squid.log | perl -ne '/(^.*? \+.*?)\..*?\s/; $a = $b = $1;$a= "\Q$a"; $b=~s/\// /g; $b=~s/(\d{4}):/$1 /; $b=`date --date=\"$b\" +%s`; chomp($b); s/$a/${b}/; print'
```

Output is now:

```
1406799892.701      0 172.16.204.59 TCP_DENIED/407 5232 GET http://vec01.maps.yandex.net/tiles? - NONE/- text/html
```